# How to call a Javascript function in the ResponseBuilder of REST function?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to call Javascript code in the client browser with various status updates Strings as argument, from my Java server side code.

A javascript code will call the following checkstatus function and I would return a call to a javascript function statusupdate
in the response.

The statusupdate() function call will have a String as a parameter like this statusupdate("statusstring")

So how can I call a JavaScript function in the response of a REST function I am using Jersey.

```
  @Path("apis")
  public class ChatAPIs {

  @GET
  @Path("/checkstatus")
  public Response checkStatus(@DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("vi") String vi){
    StatusCheckHelper statusCheckHelper = new StatusCheckHelper();

    return Response.ok(
       //I would Like to invoke a javascript function here.
      ).build();
  }
```

Comment: Please explain in details what do you mean. Do you want to call some javascript while processing the REST request and return the result of the function? Or you want to return the function code itself?

Comment: I want to call Javascript code in the client browser with various status Updates Strings as argument.

Comment: How is the client requesting `/checkstatus`? How does it handle the response?

Comment: Client is requesting through a Javascript function and as a asynchronous response to it I want to call the callback function with the response (a string) as response.

Comment: "with a a response as response"? Are you sure? May be "with a a response as an argument"?

Comment: Sorry Let me clarify I am naming the string to be returned as response

Comment: So, return string from `checkStatus()` and call your callback on client side passing to it this string. What's wrong with this?

Comment: That also can be done, but as per the requirements given to me I should invoke a function as a result checkStatus() call. Is it not possible?  then I would resort to what you have suggested.

Comment: Do yo know what function you have to invoke? Or you want to return this function from the server?

Comment: Yes I know the Name of the javascript function, its statusupdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I hope that now your question is clearer for me. You want to call RESTful API from JavaScript running on client side and then, when the response arrives asynchronously call callback function using the result returned by RESTful API.

So, the solution is the following. Your `checkStatus()` can return any type you need. For example `String`. It obviously can be wrapped by any wrapper you want but it does not matter. Javascript should take this script and call `statusUpdate(theReturnValue)` where `theReturnValue` is the `String` (or something else) that was returned by RESTful API.

If however in future you will be required to call different callback functions depending on response you can either return complex response and implement swich/case or if/else logic on client side or even return valid javascript code and call it using `eval()` function on client side.

Comment: Thanks for you patience Sir. Sometimes its difficult to convey what you really want to say.

Comment: NP. Does my answer help you? Did I finally understand you correctly?

Comment: What I actually wanted was to invoke the function from my Java code like in this line resp.getWriter().print(req.getParameter("statusUpdate") + "(" + responseData + ");");